# Model has different output for same input

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I developed a small model to recognize if a pedestrian is on a picture or not.

It achieves 99% accuracy on my test set and work very fine on my computer.

However, when I deploy it on my server, the results change and the accuracy is dropping.
And by example, for the same image, sigmoid will be :
On my computer : 0.9
On my server : 0.01

I already checked the normalization, the preparation of the datas, all is strictly the same.

The only difference is than my computer is running on a GPU, and my server, on a CPU.
I know there are always a little difference is this case (Because GPU are non deterministic), but I never had a such one.

I think it could be the `BatchNormalization` layers I use.
But why would it produce this ?

(It's the first time I deploy a model with BatchNorm on my server, so, I see only this..)

Comment: That's a huge difference. With what library do you read the picture in both cases?

Comment: Opencv for both. I already has some models deployed on my server, and that the first time it happens. That's why I tought it could be because of the batchnorm layer ..

Comment: do you use the same backend?

Comment: Yes, Tensorflow for both

Comment: During your training phase, what did you do for testing and validation?

Comment: I encountered the same issue before, and the reason that I found is the libpng/libjpeg is different.

Comment: @user36624 Thanks, I'll check the libpng/libjpeg!

Comment: @Prune Two separate sets for validation and test, as usual